# Does Django Rest Framework have a built in solution for a Validation API?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

By Validation API, I mean an API that simply takes in a field and a field type, and returns the validation result, without attempting to create, update, or delete anything.

#### Rough Example

I would want a request like this

```
curl -X POST /api/validation
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"type":"email","value":"invalid.email@@com"}'
```

To return a body like this:

```
{
  'Enter a valid email address.'
}
```

#### Use Case

Let's say you have a decoupled frontend and backend, and the backend is an API using the Django Rest Framework. In the frontend you may have a sign up flow that has several pages.

- Page 1: user enters an email, and we check if it's valid
- Page 2: user enters a phone number, and we check if it's valid
- Finally, create a user with those fields

In this flow, it would be useful to validate the email and phone number with the backend at separate times without attempting to create a User first. You wouldn't want to create a partial user with just an email, and then later patch that user to update the phone number field, because --- well because you just wouldn't want to.

Why not take care of the validation in the frontend? Because validation logic already exists in the backend, and we don't want to repeat ourselves or duplicate efforts.

#### 1) Is there a "django way" to expose existing validation logic via an API, or would this be a custom thing?

#### 2) Is this a bad idea?